# jQuery Tag Cloud Mouse hover stop it's moving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've following code of jQuery tag cloud effect. When I load the page its menu is moving BUT when I mouse hover on the menu it is also moving.

How can I stop its moving when I mouse hover on it?

**jQuery Code:**

```
$.fn.jcloud=function(settings)
{
jCloud={
    tags: new Array(),
    container_id: 'jcloud',
    radius: 100,
    size: 20,
    areal: 180,
    iterX: 0,
    iterY: 0,
    iterx: 1,
    itery: 1,
    step: 4,
    flats: 1,
    speed: 100,
    start_speed: 1,
    timer: 0,
    clock: 10,
    stop: true,
    splitX: 0,
    splitY: 0,
    colors: new Array(),
    init: function (elem,settings) {
        $(elem).css('display','none');

        var i=0;
        $(elem).find('li').each(function(){
            jCloud.tags[i]=$(this).html();
            i++;
        });

        if (typeof(settings) != 'undefined')
        {
            try {
                if (typeof(settings.container_id) != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.container_id=settings.container_id;
                }
                if (typeof(settings.radius) != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.radius=settings.radius;
                }
                if (typeof(settings.size) != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.size=settings.size;
                }
                if (typeof(settings.areal) != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.areal=settings.areal;
                }
                if (typeof(settings.step) != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.step=settings.step;
                }
                if (typeof(settings.flats) != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.flats=settings.flats;
                }
                if (typeof(settings.speed) != 'undefined')
                {
                    if (settings.speed < 1)
                    {
                        settings.speed=1;
                    }

                    this.speed=settings.speed;
                }
                if (typeof(settings.clock) != 'undefined')
                {
                    this.clock=settings.clock;
                }
                if (typeof(settings.splitX) != 'undefined')
                {
                    if (Math.abs(settings.splitX) < 2*this.radius)
                    {
                        this.splitX=settings.splitX;
                    }
                }
                if (typeof(settings.splitY) != 'undefined')
                {
                    if (Math.abs(settings.splitY) < 2*this.radius)
                    {
                        this.splitY=settings.splitY;
                    }
                }
                if (typeof(settings.colors) != 'undefined' && settings.colors 
instanceof Array)
                {
                    this.colors=settings.colors;
                }
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        $(elem).replaceWith('<div id="'+this.container_id+'"></div>');

        $('#'+this.container_id).css({
                    'position':'relative',
                    'width':this.radius*2,
                    'height':this.radius*2,
                    'overflow':'hidden',
                    'padding': '0px'
                    });

        $('#'+this.container_id).mousemove(function(e){
            var centerX=$(this).offset().left+jCloud.radius;
            var centerY=$(this).offset().top+jCloud.radius;

            jCloud.speed=jCloud.start_speed;
            jCloud.iterx=(centerX-e.pageX)/jCloud.radius;
            jCloud.itery=(centerY-e.pageY)/jCloud.radius;
        });

        $('#'+this.container_id).mouseover(function()
        {
            jCloud.stop=true, 0, 'rotate';
        });

        $('#'+this.container_id).mouseout(function()
        {
            jCloud.stop=false;
        });

        $('body').append('<div id="jcloud-buffer"></div>');
        $('#jcloud-buffer').css({
                    'display': 'none',
                    'padding': '0px',
                    'white-space': 'nowrap'
                });
    },
    render: function() {
        $('#'+this.container_id).empty();

        this.start_speed=this.speed;

        for (var j in this.tags)
        {
            this.draw(j);
        }

        this.cloud();
    },
    draw: function(id) {
        $('#jcloud-buffer').html('<div class="jtag" id="jtag-
'+id+'">'+this.tags[id]+'</div>');

        var taghtml=$('#jcloud-buffer').html();
        var width=$('#jcloud-buffer').width();
        var height=$('#jcloud-buffer').height();

        $('#'+this.container_id).append(taghtml);

        $('#jtag-'+id).attr('width',width);
        $('#jtag-'+id).attr('height',height);
    },
    cloud: function(iter,flat_iter,update) {
        var count=this.tags.length;
        var per_flat=Math.ceil(count/this.flats);
        var delta=Math.round(360/per_flat);
        var deg=0;
        var flat_deg=0;

        if (typeof(iter) != 'undefined')
        {
            deg=Math.floor(iter);
        }

        if (typeof(flat_iter) != 'undefined')
        {
            flat_deg=Math.floor(flat_iter);
        }

        var flat_offset=Math.floor(this.areal/(this.flats+1))/2+flat_deg;
        var flat_delta=Math.floor(this.areal/this.flats);

        var flat_co=0;
        for (var j in this.tags)
        {
            this.pos(deg,j,parseInt($('#jtag-'+j).attr('width')),parseInt($('#jtag-   
'+j).attr('height')),flat_offset,update);
            deg+=delta;

            flat_co++;

            if (flat_co>=per_flat)
            {
                flat_offset+=flat_delta;
                flat_co=0;
                deg+=flat_delta;
            }
        }
    },
    pos: function(degree,id,width,height,offset,update) {
        var radian=degree*Math.PI/180;
        var ell_offset=offset*Math.PI/180;
        var size_offset=0;

        var size=this.size+size_offset;

        var X=this.radius+Math.sin(radian)*this.radius*Math.cos(ell_offset)-width/2;
        var Y=this.radius-Math.cos(radian)*this.radius-height/2;

        size=(1+Math.cos(radian-1.57)*Math.sin(ell_offset))*size/2;

        if (size < 1)
        {
            size=1;
        }

        if (typeof(update) == 'undefined' || update==false)
        { 
            if (this.colors.length > 0)
            {
                for (var i in this.colors)
                {
                    if ((parseInt(id)+1) % (this.colors.length-i) == 0)
                    {
                        //$('#jtag-'+id).css('color',this.colors[this.colors.length-
i-1]);
                        //$('#jtag-
'+id).children('a').css('color',this.colors[this.colors.length-i-1]);

                        $('#jtag-
'+id).attr('style','color:'+this.colors[this.colors.length-i-1]+' !important');
                        $('#jtag-
'+id).children('a').attr('style','color:'+this.colors[this.colors.length-i-1]+' 
!important');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            $('#jtag-'+id).css({
                'position':'absolute',
                'white-space': 'nowrap',
                'font-weight': 'normal'
            });
        }

        var opacity=1;
        opacity=(1+Math.cos(radian-1.57)*Math.sin(ell_offset))*opacity/2;

        if (opacity<.5)
        {
            opacity=.5;
        }

        if (this.splitX)
        {
            var offsetX=parseInt(this.splitX);
            if (id%2==0)
            {
                X-=offsetX;
            } else
            {
                X+=offsetX;
            }
        } 

        if (this.splitY)
        {
            var offsetY=parseInt(this.splitY);
            if (id%2==0)
            {
                Y-=offsetY;
            } else
            {
                Y+=offsetY;
            }
        } 

        $('#jtag-'+id).css({
                'left':Math.round(X),
                'top':Math.round(Y),
                'font-size':Math.floor(size)+'px',
                'opacity': opacity
            });



    },
    update: function() {
        this.timer++;

        var interval=Math.floor(.1/jCloud.speed);

        if (this.timer < interval)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (this.stop)
        {
            this.speed=this.speed-(this.speed*.1);
        }

        this.timer=1;

        if (this.iterX >= 360)
        {
            this.iterX=360-this.iterX;
        }

        if (this.iterY >= 360)
        {
            this.iterY=360-this.iterY;
        }

        this.iterX+=this.iterx;
        this.iterY+=this.itery;

        this.cloud(this.iterY,this.iterX,true);
    }
}

jCloud.init($(this),settings);

jCloud.render();

jCloudInterval=window.setInterval("jCloud.update()",jCloud.clock);

}
```

Comment: There IS such a thing as showing too much code. You might want to narrow it down to the relative parts, otherwise some people could get discouraged.

Comment: Well @Praveen Kumar this is the demo http://www.shibbir.byethost7.com/tagcloud.html

Comment: suggest finding a plugin that works, should be easy to find one

Answer (score 0):

In your JS file `http://www.shibbir.byethost7.com/jcloud.js`:

```
$('#'+this.container_id).mouseover(function()
{
    jCloud.stop=false;
});
```

Change it to:

```
$('#'+this.container_id).mouseover(function()
{
    jCloud.stop=true;
});
```

Comment: @Shibbir What did you do? You did the opposite!!! You did in `mouseout` function. Not `mousemove`!

Comment: Hello, @Praveen Kumar can you fix it.